# Not able to convert an image URL to Bitmap, in Xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin

I need to convert a string image https URL to Bitmap, the solution in stack overflow does not work for me.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

}`

If i use this code, it gives me many reference error in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I guess that you want to download image from url and convert into bitmap?

If yes, I suggest you can take a look the following code:

```
private Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
    {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
            if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
            }
        }

        return imageBitmap;
    }
```

Then you can display this image in ImageView.

```
private ImageView image;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/general-9/500/add-512.png");
        image.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cherry Bu - MSFT, i wanted the downloading part only and that worked for me.